# Managing a long-running API listener using Python / Flask

Tags: python, rest, flask, redis, celery

My python script (e.g. **downloader.py**) listens to a streaming REST API endpoint which continuously sends it data. After making an initial `GET` request, it uses a function such as `requests` `iter_content()` to read the stream and then writes the downloaded data into a Mongo DB. It handles authentication and it has some logic for re-authentication if there are auth issues and pause + retry if there are certain types of errors.

The script (**downloader.py**) works well but I would like to be able to "manage" it through a web interface. Specifically, I want to be able to start the script, see if the script is running, stop the script and re-start it. Making the front end for the web interface is trivial using some front end JS or anything that makes API calls but how to encapsulate the **downloader.py** script into something that exposes a REST API which allows me to control the script? e.g. a **manage.py**

**manage.py** could be a Flask app to handle REST API calls from the web interface and then there are two options:

1. Merge them...

I could import code from **downloader.py** into the **manage.py** Flask App and use Redis/Celery to manage asynchronous long-running tasks

or

2. Keep them separate...

I could have **downloader.py** periodically poll the Flask API **manage.py** with status updates or to check for requests for termination. manage.py could launch downloader.py as a process if requested to using the API.

Some guidance as to which pattern might work better would be great. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First let's define a test streaming http server with Flask for testing purposes:

Run `pip install flask` for necessary dependencies

```py
from flask import Flask, Response, stream_with_context
import time

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/stream')
def stream():
    def generate():
        while True:
            yield 'Data\n'
            time.sleep(5)

    return Response(stream_with_context(generate()), mimetype='text/plain')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, threaded=True, port=5001)
```

It streams `Data\n` string every 5 seconds.

---

Now to create the control application and the long_running_task which will be executed by Celery worker.

Run

```
pip install flask celery redis
```

**Note** You have to install redis and run it, `pip install` is just redis client.

We can use the following code to create the control application + define the Celery task to be run (save it as app.py).

```py
import requests
from flask import Flask, jsonify
from celery import Celery, states
from celery.exceptions import TaskRevokedError

app = Flask(__name__)

celery = Celery(app.name)
celery.conf.update({
    'broker_url': 'redis://localhost:6379/0',
    'result_backend': 'redis://localhost:6379/0',
    'task_track_started': True  # Otherwise it would be possible to create multiple tasks with same id,
    # we check in start()
})

STREAM_URL = 'http://localhost:5001/stream'

task_id = None


@celery.task()
def long_running_task(url):
    try:
        with requests.get(url, stream=True) as r:
            r.raise_for_status()
            for line in r.iter_lines():  # Iterate response, delimiting by \n
                if line:
                    print(line)  # Print it to Celery worker stdout
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        print(f"Request failed: {e}")


@app.route('/start', methods=['GET'])
def start_task():
    global task_id
    if task_id is None:
        task_id = long_running_task.apply_async(args=[STREAM_URL]).id  # Start a task in Celery
        return jsonify({'status': 'Task started'}), 200
    else:
        return jsonify({'status': 'Task is already running'}), 200


@app.route('/stop', methods=['GET'])
def stop_task():
    global task_id
    if task_id is None:  # We check our global variable
        return jsonify({'status': 'No task running'}), 400
    task = long_running_task.AsyncResult(task_id)  # We fetch the task info
    if task.state == states.STARTED:  # If in other state means something went wrong, check Celery task states
        try:
            task.revoke(terminate=True)  # We terminate the task
            task_id = None
            return jsonify({'status': 'Task stopped'}), 200
        except TaskRevokedError:
            return jsonify({'status': 'Failed to stop task'}), 400
    else:
        task_id = None
        return jsonify({'status': f'Task is not running {task.state}, {str(task.info)}'}), 400


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, threaded=True)
```

You can then run both `celery -A app.celery worker --loglevel=info` and `python app.py` to start the Celeery worker and the Flask application.

---

**Note** We use global variable `task_id` to track state of the task. We can instead pass the variable `task_id` to `apply_async` but Celery does not like reusing the same `task_id`. You can also use something like [this](https://github.com/steinitzu/celery-singleton).

You can also implement `/status` endpoint which will check task state with `long_running_task.AsyncResult(task_id)`, possibly implement heartbeat with something like [APSCheduler](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/3.x/), which would probably be a good idea.

I think this gives you a pretty good boilerplate for using the technologies you mentioned to achieve your goal.

You can also achieve this by going a little lower level and avoiding Celery, creating your own task engine by spawning a new process which would execute the long running task, which would give you more control, however this is much more work, and would probably require you to implement stuff like monitoring on a system level.